# ViewModel does not exist.Simple MVVM WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, assemblies

Hi Im learing MVVM pattern for WPF to use it in my application. Im not able to bind anything, cause my XAML code says that "The name 'NAME' does not exist in the namespace 'NAMESPACE'".

My XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="mvvm.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mvvm.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <!--<Window.Resources>
        <local:MainViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>-->
    <Grid>
        <Button Width="100" Height="100" Content="Binding ButtonContent"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And I have added MainViewModel.cs. Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace mvvm.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public string ButtonContent
        {
            get
            {
                return "Click me";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Im not able to find proper solution. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: binding expressions use curly braces: `{Binding ButtonContent}`

Comment: Try rebuild your project!

Comment: Ok Im little confused. I've added curly braces and rebuild applicaton and it seems to work. So why my XAML code yield to me that I have an error, and Im not able to see my Windows in creator?

Comment: @Tatarinho, what is the error? by "creator" do you mean "designer"? I tested basically what you have shown and it works.

Comment: As I said, it's working, But Designer (you are right) see my xaml code as the error. I'm able to compile, but Visual Studio is not able to refresh view in designer.